# Simple insert statement not working. SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I seem to have run into difficulties with a simple database insert statement.
I'm inserting something into the database then (for debugging reasons) checking the number of rows. For the first example this doesn't work. For the second "rawQuery" it does. Am I overlooking something simple? I've used this method loads of times before with no problems!

This doesn't work:

```
contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("classId", cursor.getString(0));
contentValues.put("to_do", toDo);
contentValues.put("date", date);
out("SIZE OF TODO+"+fetchCount());//returns 105
db.insert("toDo", null, contentValues);
out("NEW SIZE OF TODO+"+fetchCount());//still returns 105!
```

this does:

```
out("SIZE OF TODO+"+fetchCount()); //returns 105
db.execSQL("insert into toDo values(null, "+cursor.getString(0)+", '"+toDo+"', '"+date+"')");
out("NEW SIZE OF TODO+"+fetchCount());//returns 106
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: what are the logs for first method?

Comment: I can't see any relevant logs in Eclipse for either method bar what I 'm generating myself which read `02-06 20:32:56.996: ERROR/DDD(15179): SIZE OF TODO=106
02-06 20:32:59.090: ERROR/DDD(15179): NEW SIZE OF TODO=106
`

Comment: You need to add & use the LogCat view tab as follows: Window | Show View | Other... | LogCat.  This should include a log of what exactly went wrong with the insertion.

Comment: I am using LogCat but the problem is that it fails silently, there's no reference to anything going wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such an idiot, @Rob's suggestion of looking at my create tables made me realise, I was referring to the wrong column name. It never occurred to me that an update statement like this could fail silently! Thanks @Rob

Answer (score 1):

At a guess: lines 3 and 4 are not inserting strings into the ContentValues set, but the raw objects instead. Later, some type conversion is failing. Call toString() on your parameters.

In the second excerpt, you are implicitly forcing conversion to string.

Comment: Well, I'm defining `String date="";`and `for (String toDo : toDoArray)` so surely I don't have to recast them to string?

Comment: is `date` a reserved word in SqLite? is that maybe causing a problem?

Comment: In that case, no, quite right. Can you post up your creation SQL please? e.g. CREATE TABLE ...

  If date was reserved, then by rights the creation should have failed as well, and thus your second excerpt would fail too.